# how to read parent xml by giving child value in .net

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PrimaryLink>
  <LinkID>p1</LinkID>
    <SecondaryLink>
      <LinkID>s1</LinkID>      
        <LeftMenu>
          <NavLinks>
            <LinkID>n1</LinkID>
          </NavLinks>
          <NavLinks>
            <LinkID>n2 </LinkID>               
          </NavLinks>
        </LeftMenu>
    </SecondaryLink>  
</PrimaryLink>
```

C#

```
var menuItems1 = from c in xMenuElement.Elements("GlobalNavigation").Elements("PrimaryLink")
                 select c;
```

I what the ans like `p1->s1->n1` by giving n1 as input

Comment: Sorry xml is not getting added..here is the sample xml             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <PrimaryLink> <LinkID>p1</LinkID> <SecondaryLink> <LinkID>s1</LinkID> <LeftMenu> <NavLinks> <LinkID>n1</LinkID> </NavLinks> <NavLinks> <LinkID>c<![CDATA[ ]]> n2 </LinkID> </NavLinks> </LeftMenu> </SecondaryLink> </PrimaryLink>

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Comment: how to create breadcrumb from xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution. It's not very pretty but it does what you want.

```
 string xmlContent=@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                                <PrimaryLink>
                                  <LinkID>p1</LinkID>
                                    <SecondaryLink>
                                      <LinkID>s1</LinkID>      
                                        <LeftMenu>
                                          <NavLinks>
                                            <LinkID>n1</LinkID>
                                          </NavLinks>
                                          <NavLinks>
                                            <LinkID>n2</LinkID>               
                                          </NavLinks>
                                        </LeftMenu>
                                    </SecondaryLink>  
                                </PrimaryLink>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
        var targetNode = doc.Descendants().Where(p=>p.Value=="n1").FirstOrDefault();
        string path = null;
        if (targetNode!=null)
        {
            path=targetNode.AncestorsAndSelf().Elements("LinkID").Select(p => p.Value).Aggregate((i, j) => j + "=>" + i);
        }
```

It will show "p1=>s1=>n1"

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
xmlContent its a string but i am getting nodes(var)

Comment: Everything is there excepted loading the xml data. You don't say where it comes from so I made it simple with data coming from a string. If you want to load it from a file, simply do "XDocument d = XDocument.Load("c:\test.xml");"

Comment: i want to bind this to repeator . that is link button so the corresponding url also need to fetch .. any idea?